# Wald interval of regression model

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, likelihood

I am currently doing revision for an exam on likelihood theory and am attempting the following question. I know how to construct the Wald interval for $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$, but not sure how to do it for $\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_i$?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tip:

If $\theta$ is a random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and $a$ is a real vector, there is a nice formula for variance of $a\theta$.

Can you find it?